# Php array_slice doesn't display anything

Tags: php

I have a code:

```
$salys = xprofile_get_field_data( '1237', $user_id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
```

this code displays countries in a list from user id for example:

*Andorra, Azerbaijan, Barbados, Belgium, Belize, Bhutan, Bolivia, Canada*

My goal is to limit only x amount of countries which i tried to do with **array_slice**

```
    $skaiciai = array_slice($salys, 0, 5);
```

and than echo it using

```
    echo "<textarea>";  
    print_r($skaiciai);
    echo "</textarea>";
```

But the function doesn't work, and echos nothing.

Im trying limit up to 5 countries in this scenario but it doesn't work.

EDIT 1:

With help from users in the comments i managed to limit countries my code:

```
<?php 
        global $bp;


        $salys = xprofile_get_field_data( '1237', $user_id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
        $array8 = explode(', ', $salys);

        $skaiciai = array_slice($array8, 0, 5);



        echo "<textarea>";

            print_r($skaiciai);
            echo "</textarea>";
        ?>
```

New issue is output since it gives raw input in array example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Andorra
    [1] => Azerbaijan
    [2] => Barbados
    [3] => Belgium
    [4] => Belize
)
```

Question: Do i need to do some kind of regex to clean it up?

Comment: `$salys` is not an array, it's a string. You can split it with `explode()`. (Or perhaps that `$multi_format` argument takes the value `array`?)

Comment: Ohh so this function is for array only i tough it gets array from the string field if this makes any sense. Multi format is another string which simply gives commas after each country

Comment: Correct, `array_slice()` only works on arrays. If you want to turn your string into an array, you can do `$array = explode(', ', $string);` and then use `$array` in `array_slice()`.

Comment: But wait -- don't even do that. See [the docs here](https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/xprofile_get_field_data/). As I guessed, you can pass `"array"` as the third argument and you'll get back an array, and your code should work as is.

Comment: Have edited the post with new update

Comment: Just use `echo implode(',', $skaiciai);` to get a comma separated list of countries in your textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you might want:

```
<?php 
    global $bp;


    $salys = xprofile_get_field_data( '1237', $user_id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
    $array8 = explode(',', $salys);

    $skaiciai = array_slice($array8, 0, 5);

    //remove spaces from beginning and the end of name.
    //for every element in the array
    $skaiciai = array_map('trim',$skaiciai);

    echo "<textarea>";
    //for every element in the array
    //copy the element to var $item
    foreach($skaiciai as $item) {

        echo $item . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

    }
    echo "</textarea>";
```

or use implode as @Nick advised in comment

```
    $salys = xprofile_get_field_data( '1237', $user_id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
    $array8 = explode(',', $salys);

    $skaiciai = array_slice($array8, 0, 5);

    //remove spaces from beginning and the end of name.
    //for every element in the array
    $skaiciai = array_map('trim',$skaiciai);

    echo "<textarea>";
        echo implode(', ', $skaiciai);
    echo "</textarea>";
```

to get the values in one line.

Using `','` without space instead of `', '` protects you against having items separated with comma but without a space between them in future.
but then you need to remove the space with [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and add space later if you need it.